# in IIS 7 add site specific error page settings

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, error-handling

I'm trying to setup a classic ASP page to log errors by redirecting the errors to error page that has logging enabled. When the site was migrated from IIS6 to IIS7 the logging stopped working as the details of the errors are not included in the redirect.

I have been able to fix this issues somewhat by going to the site in IIS Manager, going to that sites Error Pages, Clicking Edit Feature Settings, and Changing that option to Detailed errors for local requests, setting my default path to the error page, and changing the path type to execute URL.  In order to do this I had to edit the apphost.config and remove some of the locks that are in place there.

[image: Error Page Settings]

Now when I go to other sites on my IIS the same default page path is set on those too.  can someone please point me to some documentation or tell me how to make this change only for this particular site?

Answer (score 0):

TO do the error page per Website Deployed in the IIS you need to click on individual website and then on right hand side click on Error Pages and select the Page.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My problem ended up that I was editing my applicationHost.config which would seem like a reasonable solution, but alas it was not. Changing that XML seems to have no effect on what the IIS manager would allow me to do. I finally went into the Configuration Editor for the root of IIS and edited the same settings there, which actually had some effect. All that I had to do at that point was remove the attribute lock on default path and the then I was able to edit my site.  I have no idea why changing the application host did not have any effect. I would make the change and when I finally looked in the settings in the IIS manager, nothing I had done was changed at all...  FYI this is IIS 7.5 on Win7

Hope this helps someone else.

[image]